# Is there any Python code for Convolutional Neural Network, but without Tensorflow/Theano/Scikit etc?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I hope there will be some code where the Convolutional Neural Network will be implemented without Tensorflow OR theano OR Scikit etc. I searched over the google, but google is so crazy some time :), if i write "CNN without Tensorflow" it just grab the tesorflow part and show me all the results with tesorflow :( and if i skip the tensorflow, it again shows me some how similar results. any help please.

Comment: See for example [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6)

Comment: Thank you Friend, actually I know the normal Neural Network, I was looking for Convolutional Neural Network.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Deep Learning courses will ask the student to implement a CNN in Python with just numpy, then teach them to achieve the same result with Tensorflow etc. You can just search on Github for "Deep-Learning-Coursera" and you will probably find something like this `https://github.com/enggen/Deep-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/Week1/Convolution%20model%20-%20Step%20by%20Step%20-%20v2.ipynb`, where the CNN functions are implemented without Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it yourself from ground up.

**One way would be to just use numpy python library and implement the calculus and neurons yourself. Together with fwd si backward propagation. you can also do it without numpy, but it will probably take even more time.**

One nice example is here : https://github.com/Alescontrela/Numpy-CNN/tree/master/CNN

or this one : https://github.com/ElefHead/numpy-cnn